# integrating google maps with django

Tags: django, google-maps

am working on a project using django as the framework.i need to take input as in a location name from a text box, and submitting which should zoom that particular location in the google maps.can anyone please help me by sharing a helpful link to the information i require or any code snippets for the same.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django - it is a very basic Google Maps question, which is fully covered in the Maps documentation.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Do you see how Reto's answer below said the same thing without being condescending?

Comment: I agree. It's simply illogical to respond to questions on **a public Q & A site** with hostility.

OP I am actually working on this atm myself.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to go about this. You can use the official [Google Maps API](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/plot-one.html) but that will also give you a dynamic map, with controls and a details bubble. Here is my solution. It gives you a map as a static image.

```
img style="border: thin black solid;
     "src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
     center=***(Your '+' Separated Address)***&amp;
     size=***(HxW)***&amp;maptype=roadmap &amp;
     markers=:http://i3.ghimg.com/img/smallMapPinHover_20110214.png***(Your + Separated Address)*** &amp;
     sensor=false"
alt="Your map"/>
```

I know that's pretty huge but it's not actually that complicated if you read it carefully.

1. Replace the ***(Your + Separated Address)*** with your the address you want (eg center=123+Main+St+Orlando+FL)
2. replace ***(HxW)*** with the size you want the map to be (eg size=124x124)

The reason you have to put the address in there twice is once for the map location, and once for the pin location. You can also change "maptype=roadmap" to other things like satellite.

I hope that wasn't too confusing. Good luck!